# dir local “auto-mode-alist” sets wrong mode

Tags: directory-local-variables, auto-mode-alist

```lisp
;;; /tmp/test/.dir-locals.el
((auto-mode-alist . (("/\\.dir-locals\\(-2\\)?\\.el\\'" .  lisp-data-mode)
                     ("/[^/-][^/]*\\.el\\'"             . emacs-lisp-mode))))
```

I use `emacs -Q` to visit file `/tmp/test/.dir-locals.el`, then Emacs chooses `emacs-lisp-mode` for this file.

What goes wrong? Why not `lisp-data-mode`?

---

GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual says that the variable `auto-mode-alist` uses the first match,
so I think the pseudo-variable (I don't what is a pseudo-variable; I heard it from phils, seems like a good name) `auto-mode-alist` in `".dir-locals.el"` should also do that,
for **consistency**.

GNU Emacs Manual, 49.2.5 Per-Directory Local Variables:

> The special key `auto-mode-alist` in a `.dir-locals.el` ... works **much like** the variable `auto-mode-alist` (see Choosing File Modes).

GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual, 24.2.2 How Emacs Chooses a Major
Mode:

> If `auto-mode-alist` has more than one element whose regexp matches the file name, Emacs will use the **first match**.

However, it seems that the current behavior of dir local `auto-mode-alist` is to choose a mode from back to front.  
The reverse order is so contrary to perception.

Comment: Please say why you might expect `lisp-data-mode`. IOW, say what you say in your bug report, vis a vis the behavior difference between `auto-mode-alist` and entry `auto-mode-alist` in dir-locals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reported this as [bug#64415](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=64415); seems like it will be rejected...

---

###### To sum up

This bug is about different behavior between the variable `auto-mode-alist` and the directory variable `auto-mode-alist`.

The original behavior of how Emacs handles that dir var is to scan the alist from the back to the front, which is very counter-intuitive.

I suggest that we should make that behavior consistent with how Emacs handles the variable `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: Please summarize the bug report.

Comment: 1. Please don't ask questions in answers (except posed to the OP, to clarify the question). 2. I meant to summarize what the bug is, e.g., why you think something is wrong. I didn't mean summarizing why it was closed (but that's OK also, if you think it's helpful).

Comment: What I meant was please describe what the bug **is**, not just link to it and then summarize opinions about whether the bug should be closed. Otherwise, this is essentially a **link-only** answer. E.g., "The bug is about different/conflicting behavior between...."

Comment: @Drew: hope I understand what you mean this time

Comment: Yup; you got it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer applies to Emacs 27.x and earlier. See the note at the end for why.

---

Firstly, that's not a valid syntax for a dir-locals file -- the *top* level of the form is not a list of variables/values.

Secondly, what you're attempting is nonsensical -- dir-locals are (can be) per-mode, and so obviously the dir-locals are not checked until the buffer's mode has been set.  Changing auto-mode-alist for a buffer *after* its automatic mode has already been selected is pointless.

---

Edit: The above applies to Emacs version 27.x and earlier.  Emacs 28.1 added support for a new special top-level key `auto-mode-alist`.  Quoting `(emacs)Directory Variables` in 28.2:

```
   The special key ‘auto-mode-alist’ in a ‘.dir-locals.el’ lets you set
a file’s major mode.  It works much like the variable ‘auto-mode-alist’
(*note Choosing Modes::).  For example, here is how you can tell Emacs
that ‘.def’ source files in this directory should be in C mode:

     ((auto-mode-alist . (("\\.def\\'" . c-mode))))
```

Comment: The basic syntax is `((mode . ((var . value) [(var . value) ...])) [(mode...) (mode...)])` -- so your version is trying to target a major mode symbol `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: I just followed the example in the emacs manual.

Comment: For which version of Emacs?

Comment: 28.2 and 30.0.50

Comment: Ok, I see that Emacs 28 added support for a new pseudo-variable `auto-mode-alist` in dir-locals forms.  My answer applies to older versions of Emacs.  I'll add a note...